# Effect of the definition of a language for \documentclass

Tags: document-classes, languages

What exactly does `\documentclass[american]{article}` do with the definition of a language and in what case is it useful to define a language?

What is the difference to `\documentclass[british]{article}`?

Comment: The standard document classes (article, book, report etc.) have no such options. The [babel](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package provides hyphenation patterns for different languages (although I don't think there is an `american` or `british` option, just `english`). Is that what you are thinking of?

Comment: @IanThompson -- `babel` does have `UKenglish` and `USenglish` options, which should trigger the desired hyphenation patterns.  `english` = `USenglish` in `babel`; `canadian` and `american` also load the u.s. patterns, while `australian` and `newzealand` use the british patterns.

Comment: @barbara --- Indeed it does. It also has `british`; I should have checked the manual before commenting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Options supplied to `\documentclass` are global options and are available to all packages. So while the built in classes do not care about a language option like `american` or `british`, the `babel` package likely does.

Comment: And other packages, such as `varioref` are also aware of those idiomatic global options.