# tocloft, listoffigures and scrheadings missing page-numbers

Tags: floats, page-numbering, tocloft

There are in this example page-numbers missing at the pages containing table of contents and list of figures. Just for clarification: They're not missing in toc or list of figures but on the pages where toc and lof are located.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{dejavu} % Schriftart
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsches Wörterbuch
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % Automatische Worttrennung, auch URLs
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=alphabetic,citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % klickbare Links im PDF ermöglichen
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,includehead=true,includefoot=true,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,footskip=14pt,headsep=30pt]{geometry} % Layout anpassen
\usepackage{scrpage2} % Seitenlayout
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Grafiken
\usepackage{tocloft} % Inhaltsverzeichnis
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just 4 Test.

% Fußzeile
\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot{Seite \thepage~}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\setcounter{page}{1}

\sloppy

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[10]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[10]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1.png}
\caption[Short caption]{Long caption}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[10]

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

How to fix it without removing the current footer? What's happening there currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your given MWE.  There are several mistakes included, for example should package `hyperref` be the last called package.

I added the command

```
\ihead[Test]{Beispiel 1}        % [plain]{scrheadings}
```

to show you that the part included with `[]` is shown on the first page of a chapter or TOC and the part included in `{}` is showed on all other pages following.

I think this changes will give you what you want.

Here comes the modified and shortend MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
  12pt
 ,a4paper
 ,ngerman      % Missing in your code!
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsches Wörterbuch

\usepackage{scrpage2} % Seitenlayout
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Grafiken
%\usepackage{tocloft} % Inhaltsverzeichnis

\usepackage{lipsum} % Just 4 Test.
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % klickbare Links im PDF ermöglichen

% Fußzeile
\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot{==== Seite \thepage~======}
\ihead[Test]{Beispiel 1}        % [plain]{scrheadings}
\ohead[Test2]{Beispiel 2} 
\ifoot[Datum]{\today}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 

\sloppy

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[10]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[10]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}
\caption[Short caption]{Long caption}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[10]

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that information. **The exact solution for the problem was to comment tocloft out** (as you did). It seems, that tocloft destroys other pages containing toc's (list of figures...), too. It would be also useful to link some statements you wrote, for other users. I searched a bit for references: [Why should hyperref be the last package? See at point 2.](http://mirror.selfnet.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) and [Why define language twice?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56913/effect-of-the-definition-of-a-language-for-documentclass)